# Why does 2 pseudo elements with the same height appear visually different?

Tags: css

```css
body{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #fffa65;
}
ul{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 22px;
    display: block;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    position: relative;
}
ul li a:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
    transition: all .3s;
}
ul li a:hover:before{
    width: 100%;
}
ul li a:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
    transition: all .3s;
}
ul li a:hover:after{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css sources/menu1.css">
    <title>Menu1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason when I check it either the bottom line appear thicker(full screen) or the upper line appear thicker (when using device tool bar). ^^You can see at ul li a:before/after the height I gave it.
**Images:**

[image: Top thicker on small screen]
[image: Bottom thicker on full screen]

Tried to make some hover effect to the menu that makes a border in the top and bottom part of the menu, and as I mentioned it doesn't look the same.

Comment: subpixel rendering?

Comment: Looks like you're zoomed out on the image, so then you get subpixels. If you zoom on on this page while running the snippet, you will get the same behavior.

Comment: Whether I zoom out, or zoom in or not zooming at all the pseudos are not the same.

Comment: David A. White - I'm kind of new and playing around with coding, So I had to check what it means. And maybe it is.. I don't think anything is wrong with my code.. So is there a solution for this? Or that's just how it is..?

Comment: Welcome! This is just how it is. Subpixel rendering is different across browsers. For me, your pseudo elements look exactly the same in FireFox. They may look different in Chrome, Safari, etc. They may even appear different if the nav bar is somewhere else on the page. This is something you shouldn't necessarily worry about.